# Facebook integration with iPhone application

Tags: facebook, authentication

We have to implement SSO for our iPhone application.

We have integrated our iPhone application with facebook as per steps mentioned in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/ .

when we try to login with facebook details we are getting UserName, Name, UID, Email and Birthday details from facebook.

How can this details help me to authenticate with respect to my application.

Our application purpose is to post data to the our server(Not to facebook wall). it has basic http authentication process.

Please help how can i use facebook data to authenticate my application and perform all operations of our application.